# Analysing the dataset which was given to me with just features and no problem statement

Tags: python, dataset

I was given a dataset with some features and should show the accuracy of the model i built

I tried analysing the dataset by doing univariate and bivariate analysis but i'm not clear with the problem statement here

```
Features-
ID
Age 
Sex 
SoBL    
Onset   
FMA_pr_total    
FMA_po_total    
FIM_pr_total    
MAL_pr_AOU_mn   
MAL_pr_QOM_mn   
SIS_pr_rec  
SIS_pr_mn(%)    
SIS_po_rec  
Brunn_pr_UE prox    
Brunn_pr_UE dis 
MAL_AOU_mn ch   
MAL_QOM_mn ch   
NIHSS_pre_total 
FMA_EFFECTIVE_CHANGE
```

Please, Does anybody has any idea about this??

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to upload your .csv file to

> https://app.powerbi.com/

and get insights of the data. Microsoft Bi tool gives insights of whole your data along with the relations between the features and other insights. This may be helpful in your case to give you an idea of your data set.